# Setting field attribute as read only in hook_form_alter?

Tags: forms

I'm trying to create a simple custom module to stop the Title of a specific node being edited.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'nodetitle_node_form') {
    unset($form['title']);
  }
}
```

Currently it just removes any reference to the Title from the edit pages. Does anyone know how I can set the Title field attribute read only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [#disabled](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#disabled) attribute:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'nodetitle_node_form' && $form['nid']['#value']) {
    $form['title']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

I made the assumption that you want this when editing nodes only (not when they are being added) which is what the `&& $form['nid']['#value']` part is for.

Comment: The problem with #disabled is that it prevents submission of the disabled field as the drupal form api says...